# C# Update MySql Database not Working

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to update my MySql database but it won't work. I have inserting and selecting working fine. Not sure if it is my syntax on the query or what.

```
string id = invoicenumb.Text;
string mysqlIns1 = "UPDATE invoices SET Status = '" + 
                    comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' WHERE id = '" +
                    Convert.ToInt16(id) + "'";


            try
            {
                MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(mysqlProv);
                mysqlCon.Open();

                MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(mysqlIns1, mysqlCon);

                MessageBox.Show("Success!");
                mysqlCon.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Occured Please Try Again");
            }
```

Comment: Send more full excerpt from your code for UPDATE. You should call command.ExecuteNonQuery() somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UpdateCommand` instead of `SelectCommand`.

See [MySqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand Property](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html#connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter-updatecommand)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Stupid moment I had there.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ExecuteNonQuery()` and `MySqlCommand`.

```
       try
        {
            MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(mysqlProv);
            mysqlCon.Open();

            MySqlCommand MyDA = new MySqlCommand(mysqlIns1, mysqlCon);
            MyDA.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("Success!");
            mysqlCon.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured Please Try Again");
        }
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You are never calling `MyDA.Update()` nor you are executing the command.

Answer (score 1):

Try MyDA.**UpdateCommand** = new MySqlCommand(mysqlIns1, mysqlCon);

Instead of MyDA.**SelectCommand** = new MySqlCommand(mysqlIns1, mysqlCon);

Also, you need to call MyDA.Update() as is listed by Nick.